# Is there a way to get my mouse working correctly?

Tags: logitech-mouse

I have Logitech MK270 Combo.
The wheel button doesn't close chrome tabs; doesn't open new links, etc..
Is there a way to get it to work?

please note I'm using Deepin OS (Linux)

Comment: Have you checked your mouse settings in Deepin? I'm not familiar with Deepin's DE, but it probably has a setting for what middle click does.

Comment: I think no option for that in Control Center!

Comment: What events does `libinput debug-events` or `evemu-record` show when middle clicking?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to manually assign the middle-click.  Logitech software to customize this is available on their site:
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024703674-Downloads-Wireless-Combo-MK270

EDIT: you added that you were using "Deepin OS (Linux)" ... the page says it detects OS, so you may still have some luck.

Comment: FYI, Logitech pretty much never supplies tools like this for Linux, and looking at this, this isn't an exception.

Comment: I've had mixed success using Logitech tools on Ubuntu under WINE, so that's also a possibility.